# Synchronize code on login method

Tags: java, multithreading, authentication, synchronized

I have the following snippet of Java code in my website

```
public boolean login(String username, string password){
    if(isUserLocked(username)){
        return false;
    }
    if(isPasswordCorrect(username, password)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        increaseFailedAttempts(username);
        if(getFailedAttempts(username) > MAXIMUM_FAILED_ATTEMPTS)
        {
            lockUser(username);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code can be hacked by using a tool that sends hundreds of requests at the same time. A hacker could brute force guess hundreds of user/password combinations before the database call that locks the user is succesfully executed. What I face is a synchronous request problem. The naive thing would be to synchronize on the login method. Sure, that prevents any duplicate request from being executed, but it is also slows down the application to an unacceptable rate for our business. What are some good practies to synchronize on instead?

The following methods are relevant in locking the user, and they need to work in tandem correctly.

- isUserLocked(): goes to db to check if the field "locked" has been
  set.
- increaseFailedAttempts(): goes to db to do +1 in the attempts
  field
- getFailedAttempts(): reads the db to get the value of the
  attempts field
- lockUser(): sets the "locked" flag in the db for the
  user.

Comment: Is this running in a servlet container?

Comment: When you say that synchronizing `login()` slows down the application unacceptably, do you mean that it slows down logins too much when the server is under attack, that it slows down logins too much in general, or that it slows the application overall?

Comment: If you have a DDoS protection outside of your app, wouldn't this alone help mitigating the problem? If the attacker tries to guess passwords using brute force he has to send a lot of requests very fast (otherwise you manage to lock users), in this case something like the DDoS protection should be able stop him.

Comment: OTOH if you don't have DDoS protection he could blow up you server just by trying to hack different users - each just below your failed attempts limit. It is a different kind of attach, still bad enough as a reason to have some kind of protection against it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes it is, jboss 6.4 eap. Too slow means it is unacceptable that if 5 different people log in simultaneously, the fifth person has to wait for 5 seconds or more to get through.

Comment: @TomaszStanczak I'lltake the dos angle into our future discussions, thanks.

Comment: @user1884155 if only five people logging in simultaneously produces such a large response penalty (when `login()` is synchronized) then the `login()` method is unreasonably costly.  My answer focuses on per-username serialization, but do not overlook my second point about improving overall performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronizing the presented `login()` method is a bit heavy-handed, because that serializes access for *all* login requests.  It seems that it would be sufficient to serialize requests on a per-user basis.  Additionally, your method is somewhat of a soft target because it makes more round trips to the DB than it needs to do.  Even a single one is fairly costly -- this is likely why synchronizing the method extracts such a heavy toll.

I suggest

1. Tracking the users for which login requests are being processed at any given time, and serializing those on a per-user basis.
2. Improving the overall behavior of login() by minimizing the number of DB round-trips to at most two -- one to read all needed current data for the specified user and one to update it.  You might consider even caching these data, which you could get for nearly free if you were using JPA to access your user data.

With respect to (1), here's one way you might serialize logins on a per-username basis:

```
public class UserLoginSerializer {
    private Map<String, Counter> pendingCounts = new HashMap<>();

    public boolean login(String username, String password) {
        Counter numPending;
        boolean result;

        synchronized (pendingCounts) {
            numPending = pendingCounts.get(username);
            if (numPending == null) {
                numPending = new Counter(1);
                pendingCounts.put(username, numPending);
            } else {
                numPending.increment();
            }
        }

        try {
            // username-scoped synchronization:
            synchronized (numPending) {
                result = doLogin(username, password);
            }
        } finally {
            synchronized (pendingCounts) {
                if (numPending.decrement() <= 0) {
                    pendingCounts.remove(username);
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /** performs the actual login check */
    private boolean doLogin(String username, String password) {
        // ...
    }
}

class Counter {
    private int value;

    public Counter(int i) {
        value = i;
    }

    /** increments this counter and returns the new value */
    public int increment() {
        return ++value;
    }

    /** decrements this counter and returns the new value */
    public int decrement() {
        return --value;
    }
}
```

Every thread synchronizes on the `pendingCounts` map, but only long enough to obtain and / or update a username-specific object at the beginning, and to update and possibly remove that object at the end.  This will slightly delay concurrent logins, but not nearly so much as if the critical regions performed database accesses.  In between, each thread synchronizes on an object associated with the requested username.  This serializes login attempts for the same username, but allows logins for different usernames to proceed in parallel.  Obviously, all logins would need to go through the same instance of that class.

Comment: What should my code do if a counter reaches a certain treshold? Like, let's say the counter for one username is at 5, then what?

Comment: @user1884155, that's a policy question.  There's no essential need to do anything special at any particular count, but this approach does afford the possibility to do so.  For example, you might cause login requests to fail with a 503 error, without ever hitting the DB, in the event that that username's count is above some threshold.  That would allow you to shed a lot of load if someone is trying to brute-force a single user name.

Comment: What do you think of Tomasz Stanczak answer? It looks similar to your solution, but it's easier to implement. Is it perhaps more naive/slower?

Comment: @user1884155, Tomasz presents a simpler scheme that rejects multiple concurrent login attempts by the same username, which is a behavior that your system does not presently exhibit.  My answer focuses on queuing login attempts in a per-user fashion, so as to address the problem with minimal change to the present behavior.  The two answers otherwise have similar characteristics.  The speed is going to be dominated by the DB access either way.

Comment: Not to be dismissive of your answer (I really like the scheme), but can you think of a use case where multiple simultaneous login attempts aid a user instead of just an attacker?

Comment: @user1884155, yes: if the account is a group account then multiple group members might try to log in close together.  If it is a machine account, then multiple services on the same machine might try to log in at the same time.  If it is an authenticated web service interface then multiple distinct machines might try to log in at nearly the same time.  Basically, any kind of sharing or automation scenario could see a benefit.

Comment: Good thinking! I don't have the scenarios you describe (just plain humans doing the occassional crud operation) but I'm keeping your code snippet in my library for good measure. Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 2):

Why ever allow for more than one simultaneous login attempt?

```
// resizing is expensive, try to estimate the right size up front
private Map<String, Boolean> attempts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(1024);

public void login(String username, String password) {
  // putIfAbsent returns previous value or null if there was no mapping for the key
  // not null => login for the username in progress
  // null => new user, proceed
  if (attempts.putIfAbsent(username, Boolean.TRUE) != null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Login attempt in progress, request should be  discarded");
  }
  try {
    // this part remains unchanged
    // if the user locked, return false
    // if the password ok, reset failed attempts, return true
    // otherwise increase failed attempts
    //    if too many failed attempts, lock the user
    // return false
  } finally {
    attempts.remove(username);
  }
}
```

`ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't require additional synchronization, the operation used above are atomic.

Of course in order to speed up `isUserLocked` you could cache the lock state in a `HashMap` or maybe HTTP request – it has to be carefully implemented though.

In memory cache alone is not an option – what if a legitimate user locks himself out, calls support line to be unlocked, the unlock status gets removed from the database yet the user still cannot login because of the in memory cache?

So the content of cache should be synchronized with the database state once in a while using a background thread.

Comment: I agree that one simultaneous login attempt per username is sufficient. The problem I see with caching the lockedstate is that the cache miss amount will be very large: typically a business user doesn't login more then once or twice a day. What do you think of John Bollinger's answer? Is synchronizing on an external object better in anyway then on the write operation of a map?

Comment: The synchronization aspect of synchronizing on an external object as opposed to write operation isn’t per se any different – the `ConcurrentHashMap` uses an internal node object to synchronize, so performance-wise it is exactly the same. Now the duration of the synchronization depends on what is being done within the synchronized block and in this the `ConcurrentHashMap` seems to be very efficient to keep this part as short as it can be.

Comment: I like John’s answer – no wonder, it has directly inspired mine, it just struck me that as a legitimate user I would probably be well with only one attempt at a time. That was the point where I found this simplification to be worth publication as a separate answer. I have to admit that real simultaneousness of login attempts by the same user has its merit and I haven’t thought about it – I have been thinking about automated hacker and humans, where slowing down of automated logins seemed like an advantage.

Comment: And with regard to cache - you have always a trade-off: increased complexity, a slightly worse performance by cache miss, and faster freeing of working threads in the rare case of a cache hit. Better to make some performance and load testing to have qualified numbers regarding cost and benefit.

Comment: Let's say I launch 3 simultaneous requests. The first one will proceed correctly. The second one will be blocked, and shortly afterwards the finally block will run removing the object for that username. Then the 3 requests enters (while the first one is still doing expensive db calls). I'm afraid this third request will just enter unhindered because of the second request removing the value from the map. what am I missing here?

Comment: The second one will not go through the finally block but fail with exception. Only the first one can remove the username because all that get into login before the username gets removed will fail without going through finally block.

Comment: Isn't the definition of a finally block that the code will always run, even in the case an exception is thrown or when you return a value? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: The first sentence in the docs: "The finally block always executes when the try block exits" - you have to get into `try` first to get into appropriate `finally`.

Comment: oops I accidently put the if inside the try and didn't see that it was outside in your snippet. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that the user is locked by incrementing and checking the attempts field before you try to validate the password - this will automatically lock any user that is attempting to flood the system

```
public boolean login(String username, string password){
    if(isUserLocked(username)){
        return false;
    }
    increaseAttempts(username);
    if(getAttempts(username) > (MAXIMUM_FAILED_ATTEMPTS + 1) {
        lockUser(username);
    } else if(isPasswordCorrect(username, password) {
        resetAttempts(username);
        unlockUser(username);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I got heads up from a security expert and they said this is a no no. We display error message to the user, and the message for locked users is different than the message of invalid credentials. This is a must have. An attacker could brute force mine usernames (albeit of locked users) with this scheme, because the error message would be shown even if the password is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot is ok except that you have lots of calls against the database in a very short time. This may become a problem.

Essentially what you need is some form of rate limit e.g. a user should not have more than n login attempts per time unit (minute). This is usually achieved with a [token bucket algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket).

> The token bucket is an algorithm used in packet switched computer networks and telecommunications networks. It can be used to check that data transmissions, in the form of packets, conform to defined limits on bandwidth and burstiness (a measure of the unevenness or variations in the traffic flow). It can also be used as a scheduling algorithm to determine the timing of transmissions that will comply with the limits set for the bandwidth and burstiness: see network scheduler.

For Java there's a very nice implementation at https://github.com/bbeck/token-bucket. One bucket per username, every attempt removes one token.

Comment: Don't I need to also synchronize on each user's bucket? Otherwise race conditions can still occur. Also, lets say a 1000 request enter my application due to an attack, what's the point in the bucket blocking all of them and then every second process one for the next 1000 seconds?

Comment: Since there's one bucket per user (per user _name_ to be precise) you only need to synchronize the bucket itself but not the collection of buckets e.g. https://git.io/vKuAT. A bucket is not normally a queue in that once the bucket is empty an exception is thrown for all subsequent requests and they're discarded.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. What do you think of JohnBollinger's answer? He uses a counter instead of a bucket. Am I correct that a leaky bucket is just a counter with a refill strategy?

Comment: I have looked into the code of this Java implementation and cannot see exception throwing, if using one of two supported method calls (`consume`) it would wait until being refilled, so it could really be 1000 times processing one request per second - split on available threads.

Comment: The second strategy checks if a token is available and returns immediately `false` if not, throwing exception or discarding the request with other means is up to you. Still I see no real advantage over other answers.